# Good program to visualize file system usage on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, file-management, disk-space

Based on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows), I would like to know if there are any good programs to visualize file system usage on OS X?

I used to have SpaceMonger when I was using a PC and would love to find some alternatives for my Mac.

Comment: In Ask Different, some useful additional answers under [How can I figure out what's slowly eating my HD space?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/5353/8546)

Comment: related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at

- [Daisy Disk](http://www.daisydiskapp.com/)

> With DaisyDisk you can free up disk
>   space by quickly finding and deleting
>   big, useless files. The program scans
>   any mounted disk and displays it on
>   the sunburst map, where segments mean
>   files and folders, proportionally to
>   their sizes. The map is easy to read
>   and navigate. You can also quickly
>   preview any file and reveal it in
>   Finder to delete.

[image: Daisy Disk]

[OmniDiskSweeper](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omnidisksweeper/) is also another alternative.

> OmniDiskSweeper presents you with a
>   list of disks attached to your
>   machine. Double-click on one, and a
>   new window opens with a “column” view
>   listing every folder and file you can
>   access, which it sorts by size as you
>   watch.
>
> You then simply browse through the
>   folders and files and delete the large
>   ones which you are no longer using. If
>   a file is part of the system, it'll
>   say so on the panel (in the list of
>   Packages the file belongs to), so you
>   won't accidentally get rid of
>   something that would make your system
>   stop working. The free space on the
>   disk and the ordering of the folders
>   are automatically recalculated.

[image: OmniDisksweeper]

*OmniDiskSweeper is freeware.*

Comment: Looks like Baseline's dead :(

Comment: DaisyDisk is a paid app — the answer fails to mention it.

Comment: What Size Mac is another (paid) alternative https://www.whatsizemac.com/

Answer (score 9):

You want [Disk Inventory X](http://www.derlien.com/).

from the site:

> The layout algorithm is based on
>   KDirStat. The idea to develop this
>   program came to me when a fellow of
>   mine showed me his creation
>   WinDirStat.

[image]

Disk Inventory X is freeware.

Comment: Disk Inventory X is very buggy on Mavericks and Yosemite, and the app appears to be abandoned. Source code is freely available but it has external dependencies so it's tricky to compile on your own. Not recommended unless you use a version of OSX for which it was originally compiled.

Answer (score 7):

[GrandPerspective](http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net/) is an Open Source app that will do what you're asking.

[image]

Comment: mmmh, this one seems to show only "blocks" while I actually like to be able to navigate through folders and files.

Answer (score 7):

[JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/) is available as a [JAR file](http://www.jgoodies.com/download/jdiskreport/jdiskreport-1_3_1.zip).  It will run anywhere that a JRE is installed, including your Mac.

[image]

Comment: JDiskReport is handy for any Java-capable OS

Answer (score 3):

[WhatSize](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/13006/whatsize) ($13) and [Baseline](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/26055/baseline) ($20) both show you a view of all folders sorted by size which you can drill down into (among other view options). It is a little hard to describe, but much more useful than the graphical view of many of the other apps that have been listed. Baseline has more features such as making snapshots of your disk usage to compare to your current usage, but it is the more expensive of the two.