# How to determine the size of disk storage in macbook air?

Tags: hard-drive

My computer is supposed to have 500 GB of disk storage but I only have access to 250 GB.
How can I determine for sure the real size ?
Please, also explain what does the following mean ? It's the result of running "diskutil list" command
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/1136012/how-much-storage-should-be-taken-up-by-system-in-macos-sierra

Comment: No, it actually make me aware of another problem and not presenting a good solution for me.

Comment: Diskutil says you have 250GB. Double check in the Disk Utility GUI app, set View to 'Show all devices' then select the actual drive, not one of the volumes. That should confirm it.