# How do I stop MacBook from filing up disc space without me doing anything

Tags: macbook

I have a MacBook 2010 running High Sierra. I watch as my disk space disappear literally within hours. The MacBook then become unusable and I have to reboot with a power button. My disk space goes from 80gb free space according to Finder and About this Mac - Storage to 20gb or less free space. At 20gb it is unusable and I have to reboot.

All the space comes back after reboot and the process starts again. None of the solutions I searched for worked and this still happens daily.

I ran antivirus, malware and any utility that was recommended, even did a reinstall of OSX.

What keeps using the space and how do I stop it

Please help

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-hd-space

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good program to visualize file system usage on Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/86194/good-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-mac)

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions recommended. Just one thing, they all show you how to check what was using the memory and deleting the offending file, but none so far could help me stop the fact that as soon as the file is cleared my MacBook started filling the disk space  again. It was as if something was installing in the background. I think I may have found the culprit. By process of elimination it looks like Spark email client was the software ding this.

I have uninstalled it from my MacBook for a few days now and the problem seem to have disappeared. Unfortunately no Support from Spark, they told me to search for a solution as they do not respond to emails privately.

Tx