# where is my free space

Tags: windows-xp, disk-space, pinnacle-studio

I'm using Pinnacle Studio 12 to edit some videos and as you can guess it uses a lot of resources. The problem is that it eats all my free space from the C drive and after I close the application I don't get back my free space. I assume it does swap some files but where and why it doesn't delete them?

I don't store the project and saved files on C drive.  I'm running Pinnacle Studio 12 on a XP sp3 Windows machine. I've tried to clean my system with CClean, but it doesn't find/see where my space is lost!

TY

Comment: In general, to find out what is using your disk space, you can find programs at this other question: http://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you manually checked the following folders?

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Home\Local Settings\Application Data\Pinnacle Studio
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Pinnacle Studio
C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Pinnacle Studio
C:\Program Files\Pinnacle Studio
```

Comment: many thx for the great general idea answer and for editing my question.

Answer (score 9):

http://windirstat.info/ will give you a wonderful graphical representation of your hard drive, organized by folder.

You can also find other programs to visualize disk space at [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows).

Comment: definite +1 for this tool...best graphical representation IMO

Answer (score 3):

I don't have access to Pinnacle that new but in Pinnacle 9 all the intermediate and temporary files are saved in `%HOMEPATH%\Pinnacle Studio\Auxiliary Files\<project filename>\`.

If that yields no results, I'd try the Windows' default temporary file locations: `%TEMP%` and `%WINDIR%\Temp\`.