# Where is my HDD space?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [where is my free space](https://superuser.com/questions/132889/where-is-my-free-space)

**Recently I have noticed that my HP Pavilion G 6 has gotten quite slow and now I'm missing a lot of space.**

Comment: Please provide more details.  How big is the HDD supposed to be?  How big is it showing?

Comment: Along with providing more details, please take a minute to review the [faq] and [How to ask](http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask) for more information about how to get good answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a `chkdsk /f` on the drive to make sure it has structural integrity.