# Want to know fast the biggest files on my PC

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best program to visualize file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-Windows)

Best way to map file sizes on a PC (Windows XP)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the portable version of [WinDirStat](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/windirstat_portable).

[image]

Comment: I love this program so much because I can actually visualize where my space is going.

Answer (score 5):

[TreeSize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/index.shtml) for sure, with a simple tree based view of what is eating your space. You can even have filters. While you can choose to view by size on hard drive you can also view it by percentage (of a parent folder) and file count.

[image: TreeSize Free]

Comment: Boo-hiss! WinDirStat does that plus has a separate graphical breakdown. It's also smaller and portable.

Comment: @taspeotis: you're quite right. I've used WinDirStat before but was put off by **how slow** it was compared to TreeSize. (Try a folder with heaps of mixed sized items in various nested depths like *C:\Program Files*)