# how can i tell whats takign up all my hard drive space?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best program to visualize file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows)

does anyone know a free software that will graph the directories on my hard drive and sort them in order of largest size?

or provide me a solution for me to quickly determine what drives/ files are consuming my hard drive space?

Comment: dupe of http://serverfault.com/q/219018/46792 by same user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[windirstat](http://windirstat.info/) has great reviews and is free

Answer (score 0):

I am currently loving [TreeSize](http://download.cnet.com/TreeSize-Free/3000-2248_4-10139400.html?tag=mncol;1) freely downloadable from [download.com](http://Download.com)