# Where did my disk space go?

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best program to visualize file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows)

I just bought a new pc. I have 2 hard drives. One is C, an SSD HD of 60 gb where is installed Windows and the other is a normal HD of 2tb.

When i started the first time my computer I found that the space on C was just 20 gb. Someone told me to move the paging file to D so now i have 34gb, but im still missing 10 gb.Im really worried as i need to install some software that requires 10/15 gb of space.

Can someone help me to know where these 10 gb are and if there is some opportunitis to create more space on C?

Comment: More than likely it is being used by Windows System Restore Points.

Comment: Some may be lost to the great gods of Manufacturer Megabytes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive#Capacity_measurements  And a page from Apple suggests that 5GB can be lost that way on an iPod, which would be comparable to what you would loose with Windows... http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=1803224

Comment: SSD drives have a 'reserved' section for failed cells. It's often included in disk size specs.

Answer (score 1):

very hard to say without looking at the Disk management?

Can you send a screen shot of your disk management on here? To get this go to

Start --> Control Panel -->Administrative Tools -->Computer Management-->Disk Management

This might provide a few more answers to your missing space

Comment: I went to disk managment but it not seems there are a lot of informations, i have a screen capturer but dont know how to upload on here

Comment: you will have to uploa the pic somewhere and provide a link to it on here using the following syntax. { ![Network Diagram][1] } minus the curl braces and then put the following {  { [1]:http://www.whateverthelinkis  }

Comment: I follewed someonline tutotials and i reduced the percentage og the restore points usage and now seems that i recovered 10 gigs :)

Answer (score 1):

JDiskReport ( http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/ ) is your friend.

I find this little tool invaluable in finding where all my hard drive space has gone.

Answer (score 1):

Or try TreeSize Pro,  which analyzes your disk space and provides the results in clear statistics and diagrams: http://www.jam-software.com/treesize/ (free trial for 30 days)