# Windows 7 Home Basic - disappearing hard disc space

Tags: windows-7, windows

Hi I am running Windows 7 Home basic on a mini computer operating some test equipment. The hard drive is only small 7.58 GB.I installed Adobe 10 as I was receiving a pop up informing me that the version installed [5] was not compatible. Long story short I uninstalled version 10 and wanted to reinstall 5 as the pdf report print from the equipment software wouldn't work. I also updated the free Antiver Anti virus programme installed. Suddenly it informed me that there was insufficient space to install version 5. On checking the available free space I noticed there was 29MB free and while I was watching the free space disappeared before my eyes down to zero?? I have run defrag no luck. There is no space to install any sort of priogramme to investigate the problem.What is causing this? Any suggestions would be appreciated thanks

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/251510/where-did-my-disk-space-go & http://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows

Comment: May you use this to see whats going on ? http://www.folder-size.com/

Answer (score 2):

The tool I find best for checking where hard drive space is being used in [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info).  It'll provide a graph to show where space is being used.

You should also make sure the Hibernation is completely disabled.  You can do this by opening a command prompt with Administrator rights and typing in:

```
powercfg -H OFF
```

You can also reduce the size of the page file.  Go to `Control Panel` -> `System` -> `Advanced` and change the page file settings to something like `256MB` minimum and `1024MB` maximum.

Answer (score 0):

8GB would be enough if you were running Windows NT but you are not... Windows 7 is a hard drive hog it could have been one of many things increasing in size... an update downloading(Windows,Antivirus,Something Else), Prefetch Growing...

Looking at my Windows **Folder** it alone is over 14GB so I don't see how you manage with just 8GB and applications.

Comment: The problem with looking at the size of the Windows folder is that Explorer double-counts loads of hardlinked files from the WinSxS folder.  As a result, you get a number considerably higher than the actual disk usage.

Comment: When I look at all my files together and actual disk usages the difference is only like a 1GB so its not that much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows 7 requirements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/system-requirements) say you need 16 GB for 32-bit, 20 GB for 64-bit.  You're pushing your luck to start with...

But it's probably possible to get it running if you strip the system down enough.  It'll be a neat trick to keep it under control, though.

Likely, if it's a freshly installed system, Windows Update is pulling down SP1 or something, which will probably need every bit of space you have to spare, just to get downloaded, never mind installed.

Defrag is useless; I don't know why people run it at the drop of a hat.  It's not even **supposed** to help with this kind of problem.

Places to go hunting for disk space...

- Clobber temp files and internet cache.

  Disable the hibernation file:  powercfg.exe /hibernate off

  Uninstall unneeded programs or Windows components (Control Panel, Programs and Features).

  If you have enough RAM in the system to operate without one, disable the pagefile.

You could probably strip out some of the Windows system files related to extraneous crap you don't need, but that's more detailed than I'm comfortable trying to guide you through over the web, specially since I can't guesstimate your needs.

Anyway, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To recover *some* space, and **only** if you don't use automated backup programs, type in

```
FSUtil USN DeleteJournal /N C:
```

in the command prompt.

However, to free up most of the space, you will likely need to remove the system restore points and backups (volume "shadow copies"); follow the instructions [here](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/07/01/disable-and-turn-off-system-restore-shadow-copy-in-windows-vista/) and/or [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5880891_delete-shadow-copies-vista.html).

Comment: What does your FSUtil Command do?

Answer (score 0):

You may use treesize free edition ( http://www.google.nl/search?q=treesize+free ) to see what directories and files are using disk space. Maybe you find some temp files that you can remove.