# Need tool to see why I keep running out of hard drive space on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, software-rec, file-management, storage

I see a lot of previous questions being asked here about visualizing hard drive usage.  Maybe those would be helpful, but I really need to find out why my 64 GB hard drive in Windows 7 keeps running out of space without me doing much to it.  Every couple weeks I need to free a GB by removing applications or whatever I can possibly find.  I'm just about to run out of apps and files to delete!  I have another 128GB hard drive in this computer, but apps don't run correctly when the main `C:\` drive runs out of space...

I've right clicked for details of individual folders in C: and drilled down that way... but it's very time consuming and I'm not sure all the numbers add up properly!  virus scans don't show anything funny.

I guess I'd love a tool that not only visualizes or clearly lists file/directory storage, but shows me within a time frame where space is taken up.  Like for the past 2 weeks, where's the data?

Comment: Have you _tried_ using any of the tools suggested on other questions? If you ran some of the software suggested [program to visualize file system use](http://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows), you might be able to figure out what's taking up space. It's most likely temp storage, logs, etc.

Comment: since I had slightly different requirements, I figured I'd ask... kind of the whole point of this site...

Comment: @nhinkle: +1. First you identify what's taking up the space, then you figure out why, then you fix it.

Comment: your requirements are slightly different indeed, which is why I didn't close your question as a duplicate on sight. It would be appreciated though if you would tell us what steps you've already taken, and if you've actually _tried_ any of the software already recommended for this sort of problem.

Comment: I've now tried a bunch of the programs and none of them give you an idea of how much space is being eaten up within a period of time, I was able to figure some things out with treesize by softonic (easier than the rest even without a visualization).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try [here](http://directory-size-download.com/) this software shows your directories and where the HDD is being used. Also try [here](http://treesize.en.softonic.com/).

Comment: While neither software shows me quickly and easily what's eating up my space the most within a timeframe, I was able to figure some things out with treesize much better than windows' file manager.