# My c drive shows less size then it should be

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best program to visualize file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/best-program-to-visualize-file-system-usage-on-windows)

I have  2 partition on 80 gb hdd. C drive is of 29gb. The property shows that used space is 28.5gb. But when I select all the folders in c drive it shows property of 16gb. So there is a more then 10gb space which is not freed on my drive. Kindly help for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The missing space is most likely in the Recycle Bin or in other hidden folders.  Depending on your OS version, it may also be in other user folders if you have UAC enabled.

Whenever I need to figure out where disk space has gone, I typically use [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/).  It makes it pretty easy to see what's using disk space.  I also typically use [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to clean the disk of unnecessary garbage in the form of temp files and such.  Be careful with the latter, however, as you are deleting files with it.

Answer (score 1):

Also, dependent on the OS, your file system may need checking using something like chkdisk to find file and table entries that don't match, etc