# Is there a way to see which files are taking up the most disk space in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visualize the file system usage on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

I am running out of disk space on my Windows 7 machine and I would like an easy way to list files by size.  Is there a utility that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 3):

WinDirStat
http://windirstat.info/

Answer (score 2):

There are a plethora of tools out there to show you disk usage/file size visually. My personal favorite is [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) just because I like pretty colors. Since you are on windows 7, you could also run this in powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\* -recurse | sort-object -property length -descending | Select-object  -f 10
```

Which would list the ten largest files on the C Drive.

Comment: A portable version of WinDirStat is here: http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/windirstat_portable

Answer (score 0):

[TreeSize Free](http://TreeSize%20Free) is a free utility which shows disk space usage by directory (and by subdirectory tree), which might be useful to you.

Answer (score -1):

A simple search based on file size will tell you.  Perhaps start by looking for "Huge" files and see if anything jumps out.  There are certainly other tools but the built in search is a good start