# Find out what's sapping hard drive space?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2003, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Visualize the file system usage on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

I have a machine running Windows Server 2003 R2 and over the last week, the available hard drive space has been dropping dramatically. Is there a program that exists that I can install on the server that will watch what files are being ADDED to the drive? I can use WinDirStat and find out when files were last modified, but there are about a hundred users that modify their files every day. If I were able to look at only newly created files, that may point me in the direction of what is killing approximately 6GB a day.

Comment: Not really a duplicate. He wants something like windirstat, but only for the last day, not for the whole disk. I don't think windirstat does that by date.

Comment: Yeah, WinDirStat is just a snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

It will not do it real time, but why not just use Windows' search function by date, then sort the results by size? This will not just show files created, but all files, but I suspect that with you losing 6GB/day, that won't matter, and the answer will stick out like a sore thumb.

[image]

You can also play around with the `dir` command with options similar to this: `dir *.*  /s /o-d-s /tc >c:\temp\dir.txt` The /o-d-s sorts them by date and size, the - means do it newest first and largest first, and the /tc means use the create date. The /s is common and searches sub-directories, and the only annoying thing is is that I cannot get it so sort the entire drive as one unit, rather than by directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are sure the disk usage is not due to shadow files, backups, logs or anything else locally created by the server.

The quick and easy way to audit file creations on the network shares. . .

If you have a lot of users though, that doesn't really get to the crux of the problem. I would turn to a  a tool like [Disk Usage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651) that logs the size of each folder.  Watch the logs for a couple of days to narrow down the folders in quesiton. With those folders in question, you can then monitor file activity with AD auditing.  With this information, you can talk to the users about their file usage patterns.  Then, if you haven't already, I'd talk to management about laying out ground rules for disk usage.