# How do I delete everything on a partition, except for Windows?

Tags: windows, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I free up some space in my C: drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/305645/how-can-i-free-up-some-space-in-my-c-drive)

I am running Windows 8 on a seperate partition right now, and want to delete everything on my old partition that contains Windows 7, except for the Windows 7 OS (just in case). How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is rather ambiguous. Are you trying to uninstall programs on the Win7 partition, or delete files, or what? What is the purpose of deleting "everything"?

Comment: I want to free up disk space, so that I can allocate the free space from the Window 7 partition and merge it with my Windows 8 one. I just want to keep the Windows 7 install, just in case anything goes wrong.

Comment: Use disk imaging software and make a image of the W7 partition and mbr. Now you can delete everything, if things go bad you can restore the image you made to that partition.

Answer (score 2):

1. Uninstall all the items using [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/).
2. After doing that, create a new user account and delete the rest in the

   > C:\Users   folder
3. Run [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)
4. [Finalize a service pack of Win 7](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/44317/should-you-delete-windows-7-service-pack-backup-files-to-save-space/).

Comment: Why can't he just uninstall using Windows' Programs and Features?

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Revo Uninstaller does the job better

Comment: In what ways does it do it better?

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Removes stuff from registry that the uninstaller fails to remove, clears the Appdata ..

Answer (score 1):

I would just delete everything and reinstall the Windows 7 partition (don't install anything yet), defrag, then select the partition size. On my box, I have like 200g of free space in my Windows partition because I installed programs before I partitioned the drive, and there were some unmovable files. To prevent this error in the future, I am always going to reformat the entire drive, and leave a few partitions free for changes in the future.