# Windows XP and folder sizes

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

I'm trying to find out the easiest way to check folder sizes to see how big each are.  Why is it that when you view the folder details, the size never shows up?  It was always blank. I have to highlight the folder to find out the size of its contents.  What is the easier way to check multiple folders at one time?

Answer (score 3):

You can try [Foldersize](http://foldersize.sourceforge.net/);t shows graphs and scales for each folder, and the total space within the folder

Answer (score 1):

Select the folder(s) and hit `Alt+Enter`

Comment: This seems to show the total size of the selected folders and not the sizes for each folders. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: ahh, misunderstood the question then

Answer (score 1):

If you need just the size of that one folder, just Select all objects. It will give you the size at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [this](http://foldersize.sourceforge.net/) shell extension.  It runs as a service in the background and works pretty nicely.  The installation process is a bit unusual, but the instructions on the site are clear and straightforward.

[image]

Comment: That was the program I suggested