# Graphical Monitor for HDD usage

Tags: windows, software-rec, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

I'm on Windows XP and find myself running fairly low on space. Unfortunately upgrading my drive is not an option, so I'd like to find a way to profile my disk usage. I would prefer something graphical, but I could settle for something text based.

Are there any tools built into Windows, from Sysinternals, or perhaps as a third party solution, that might be able to get me the data I need?

Thanks!

Comment: ...and I can't recommend the top voted answer on that question enough (although I do hate the graphical interface it has).

Comment: @Shinrai Excellent! I guess I had been searching for the wrong terms.