# Windows 7 RAID disk size incorrect

Tags: windows, raid

I have 2 drives at 500gb each installed.  I used the Windows storage manager to create a software mirror.  Now I'm getting several disk full messages, and my C:\ reports having as few as 8MB free space left often.  I then start uninstalling apps, clearing temp, etc., just to make room to keep using my system.

When I check the properties of all of the files in the C:\, it's reported as 113GB size on disk.

Seems to me that there is either some massive hidden file(s) taking up space, or that the RAID is simply reporting the incorrect values.

Comment: What does Disk Manager say about the disk space/size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Comment: I can't see the usage in storage manager, but it reports the disk size correctly as 463GB.  With 113GB of disk used, you'd think I'd have plenty left to play with.

Comment: Are you certain your partition is actually using all of the mirror? Sounds likely to me that it is not.

Answer (score 1):

I was obtaining the values for Size On Disk by selecting all of the folders on the root of C:.  It wasn't picking up folders that I don't have access to under that account.  Found a nice 380GB folder in there.

Mystery solved.