# is there a tool I can use that will show me the size of directories visually?

Tags: windows-7, windows, maintenance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

I was listening to the StackExchange podcast (either 28 or 29) and Jeff briefly mentioned a tool that you could use to see the size of directories. I may be completely wrong.

Anyway, is there a tool I can use to browse directories and get a visual indicator of their size? I need to clean up a hard drive and this would be a big help.

Comment: I did search for this before I posted but I looked for "windows size directories" and didn't see what I wanted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try WindirStat.  It's excellent giving both a visual and text that both work together.  Selection one highlights the other, etc. http://windirstat.info/download.html

Comment: http://windirstat.info/index.html shows how the interface looks.

Comment: Nice tool. Even better: it reports the correct last modified date for folders. In my case Win7 says 12/6 but I know it's been mod'd since then. WinDirStat says 12/10 which is much more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I love WinDirStat when I am cleaning and doing in depth analysis.  When I just need a quick complete status of any particular branch of a directory tree I prefer [TreeSize free](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/). Right click integration and very fast reporting make it a great addition to the toolbox.

If these two don't meet your needs, I also stumbled on a list of similar tools that seems pretty interesting https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=pQUddA0IZ9qvu_A3TvLu3cA&gid=2&output=html