# Where are 25 GB of missing disk space on my SSD?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

I highlighted all files and folders in my C drive (with "show hidden files or folders" switched on) in Windows 7 Professional x64, and went on right click > "Properties", where I found out that the total size is 73.3 GB.

However, in the "My Computer" screen it's telling me that I have 12.5 GB free of 111 GB which means that I have 25.2 GB Unaccounted for.

Any ideas why? And if it can be solved, how would I do this?

Comment: Your right-click-Properties probably doesn't account for System Restore Points and other special file sets.

Comment: Your recycle bin has some reserved, Page file, System Restore Points, etc.

Comment: Yeah, select all + properties fails when there are files you can't select at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to allocate it with [Disk Management](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309000) ([guide2](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/), [guide3](http://ancillotti.hubpages.com/hub/Using-Disk-Management-in-Windows-7-Vista)).

You didn't give enough details, but maybe you simply don't allocate all the space.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the other posters have said you are a little light on details, Personally I think a large portion could be taken up by the recycle bin. Empty the recycle bin and see if that frees up the space.

I would also recommend the freeware program [Space Monger](http://www.sixty-five.cc/download/) (Versions after 1.4 are not freeware). It will give you a visual representation of what is using up all of your hard disk space.

Answer (score -1):

[This explains some of it.](http://lifehacker.com/5802838/how-to-maximize-the-life-of-your-ssd)

Basically, SSDs writes everything in blocks, and it doesn't overwrite a block when writing to the disk unless you specify it to. I hope you're not using your SSD to store ALL of your programs/data =D

EDIT:

[Jeff Atwood talks about his experience with SSDs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/05/the-hot-crazy-solid-state-drive-scale.html)

Comment: well I'm using it to store my programs their data and the OS ... which makes my pc run much faster (all other data is stored on other hard drives). :/

Comment: Basically, every time data has to be written to the hard drive, it creates a new block, thus why actual data written can be vastly different from how many blocks are being used up on the disk. Blocks can only be overwritten if they are completely removed and then remade, which forces the SSD to rewrite all of the information in a block, thus shortening the life-span of the SSD exponentially more. Created an edit from a Jeff Atwood post on his experience with SSDs