# Display Folder Size in Windows 7 Explorer

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)
> [Folder size display in Windows 7 and Vista](https://superuser.com/questions/11872/folder-size-display-in-windows-7-and-vista)

Is it possible to display the folder size in Windows 7 explorer like this:

[image: Screenshot]