# Free space on brand new asus zenbook 64 SSD is only 15 Gb

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

I just bought a Zenbook with a 64GB SSD. But free space on the disk is only 15GB (I have only installed Google Chrome)?

Is this normal? I've checked the Windows folder and that's only 10GB. The rest of the folders is no more than a few GB's, so how can I have only 15GB available?

#### Update:

There is 8GB for Microsoft Office so I uninstalled that.
Now, why does Windows 7 take up so much space (21GB)?

Comment: I know how to visualize. My question is rather why brand new windows eats so much.

Comment: @ekaj I looked at partition 8 Go is taken I guess for factory restore and the rest is c partition described in my post.

Comment: They're gb's (gigabytes, right?) because I have no idea what a Go is..

Comment: In one sentence you say win7 takes up 10GB in the other that it takes 21GB. how does this come? Have you checked the size of the partition, is there a recovery partition maybe? Whatever, the question `why does windows take so much space` is not really a good fit for SU.