# Hidden files that impossible to see Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

In the propeties of directory `C:/Documents and Settings` it says that it contains 26,937 files and take up 15.3 GB. The directory consists of two directories: `Administrator` (67 files and 5.1 MB) and `All Users` (1,238 files and 185 MB). There are no additional files or directories shown after I choose "Show hidden files" in Tools. How can I see what files or directories get most space under `C:\Documents and Settings`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [TreeSize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/). This utility will let you see which folder takes the most space, in a tree view.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]