# HDD went full while screen recording

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space, buffer

I was using CamStudio 2.7, while all af a sudden I got a message from vista stating that my drive is full. I checked my drive and indeed there were only 30MB left(from ~7GB which were before the crush). Some minutes ago this went to 4kB!

I restarted my laptop, just in case the was a full buffer but all I got was 300MB. After some minutes this went to 2GB. What is going on here?

Keep in mind that CamStudio crushed while recording.

I used TreeSize to see whether there is something wrong, but I didn't find anything.
I also checked with AVG to see if there is a virus but again I found nothing.

What can I do to have my free space back?

Comment: Why not just delete some stuff? Which "windows tools" did you try? See: http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows

Comment: @techie007: Thank you very much for your comment! The thing is that there where ~7GB free space, the CamStudio crushed and after that my free space was 1kB! I rebooted and now it's ~2GB. So I didn't saved the recording. I searced through temp and CamStudio's Directories but I found nothing in there... The "tool" I used was `TreeSize` but I didn't find anything suspicious...

Answer (score 1):

Delete your screen recordings, obviously. I recommend compressing them using a better format then deleting the originals.

I recommend using a program like SpaceMonger to "see" where your space is going. http://www.sixty-five.cc/download/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I used `TreeSize` but I didn't find anything suspicious. CamStudio crushed, while recording so there were no recordings saved. I checked on temp, videos, CamStudio's directories, but I found nothing...