# How to clean C drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

I am using windows 7. I never installed any software to C drive. However some something just keeps eating C drive without my permission. How can I clean my C drive without re-installing my OS? Also, I believe there are lots of junks which are not deleted when I uninstalled the programs. I tried CCleaner but it cannot find them. Is there a way to find them?

Comment: moo0 disc cleaner

Comment: You might also want to right click on drive, then properties, then "Disk Cleanup..." to see if Windows sees some potential to cleanup files.

Comment: I've edited your post. Please avoid including irrelevant information and don't ask two questions at once. By the way, the books question was a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and would be closed as such.

Comment: Related: [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Comment: If something "keeps eating" your C drive, you should at least be able to identify the files that are taking up the space.  (But keep in mind that the OS will put all sorts of stuff on the C drive.  How much space is being "eaten"?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run a utility like [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) and find out what is eating up your drive.

Comment: One of the safest. I use it all the time

Comment: Yes, it is open source project. Very nice one! Hope I can vote you up, but I need at least 15 rep to do that.

Comment: No, worries. Did you figure out what was taking up space?

Comment: Yes, it works like charm. I found a 20 gigabyte backup folder. WinDirStat is really great, but is there a way to find other junks which do not cost much disk space?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Visual Studio installs it's files into `%APPDATA%` or `%LOCALAPPDATA%` folders and into `C:\ProgramData` folder in Windows Vista/7/8. Things like help always come there. So check your registry (especially check `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders` and other entries like `Explorer\Shell Folders`) and decide to move these folders to another drive.

You can make this by two paths:

- change value of registry variable (advantage is that it is available in *any* Windows version)
- or move the folder and create link (unix way, advantage is that you can move only specific folder and retain others).