# How to display the size for folder in windows explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

Just wondering that if there is a way to display the size of folder in size column inside of windows explorer? by default, it only display the size of a file, you have to use right click and properties or other way to check the size of a folder. I searched online, there are some 3rd party tools or explorers can do this.

I m just looking for some native way built into windows to show folder size if any one knows how.....

Comment: The reason that folder sizes are not displayed in a list view is because it could be resource intensive. To calculate the size of a large folder with many files and subfolders could take a long time, then put 20 of these in a list and it will be a total drag on the system. That's not to say its impossible and I look forward to any answers.

Comment: MS doesn't appear to have implemented it, but it sounds like there are some third party applications: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/ce998316-c210-4cdb-a38b-69be223a305f/folder-size-in-explorer-windows-7?forum=w7itproui

Comment: I m using Q-dir for long time, it has kind of function, but not in windows explorer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

To get the sizes of folders, I use [**WinDirStat**](https://windirstat.net/)

[image: WinDirStat example screenshot]

This is not exactly what you are asking for, but hopefully still helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs you can use a simple VBS Script:

```vb
Dim oFS, oFolder
Set oFS = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFolder.GetFolder("c:/Temp")
WScript.Echo Round(oFolder.Size/1024/1024,3) & " MiByte"
```

You can bring it down even to a single line:

```vb
WScript.Echo Round(WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder("c:/Temp").Size/1024/1024,3) & " MiByte"
```

Answer (score 0):

Folder size, the best app ever.
http://foldersize.sourceforge.net/
[image]