# Disk capacity in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, filesystems, file-management

I have a disk which has the capacity of 476 GB. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit. I want to check how much storage I've used on the C:\ drive.

The normal thing is to go to the "computer", and check the capacity property. According to the property I have used 324 GB.

When I enter the C:\ drive and select all files and folders (which are "Windows", "Users", "Program Files", "Program Files (x86)" ect...) and go the capacity property it says that the size on disk of these files is 100 GB.

Where is this 224 GB?

Comment: [Proper](http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows) research before you ask a question is mandatory here at Superuser.

Comment: [Show hidden and system files](https://www.google.com/search?q=show+hidden+and+system+files) before doing it.

Comment: The answers in the linked 'duplicate' post do not really help and do not answer the OPs problem. The one answer below adresses the problem better but does not suggest a solution. And since the thread was closed, I cannot do that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The seemingly missing space can be occupied by many sources.  The three most common candidates are:

- Other partitions (including hidden ones)
- Hidden/system folders
- System Restore files