# How to resize Users folder on Windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have windows 7 64 bit installed. In c drive, there is Users folder which is full of empty folders but it occupies almost 50 GB on my c drive. Is this normal and is there a way to shrink it? please. thanks. (note: my c drive is 200 GB in total).

Comment: You don't have to "resize" it and there is no such option, it should be some hidden file, the friendly way to view hidden file for is use some 7-zip or WinRAR zip software

Comment: Users folder full of empty folders already sounds weird & them taking 50 GB is way too much. Try to find out why are there empty folders, look deeper after un-hiding hidden + system files or advanced tools like space sniffer or windirstat...

also look around http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows

Comment: Thanks. I found out Username/AppData/Local/Temp folder is full of files especially temporary photoshop files (which are huge up to 15 gb) and deleted them. it seems ok now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a clean install, right?  This is an upgrade of an existing system?

You can use [Disk Quotas](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ntfs+quotas) to limit directory sizes, but your real question seems to be why you have a 50 GB Users directory.

Note that the Users directory includes a directory for each account on the system, and then there are subdirectories for lots of common items - e.g. Downloads, My Documents, My Music, My Videos, the Desktop, etc.

While there are likely lots of empty directories, there probably is a valid 50 GB of content there.  Probably worth drilling down a bit and trying to find the actual files.

Comment: One of those TreeSize, disk content size, type of programs that easily sort the folders by size can really assist in discovery of what is taking up space.