# 64GB Surface claims to hold 74GB, tries to copy 160GB worth of data

Tags: windows-8.1, backup

Before I leave on vacation, I decided to do a full backup of my Surface Pro 2.

The Surface itself is 64GB (~54GB available) so I decided to see how full it is to see if it would fit on my backup drive.

I went into `C:/`, highlighted all the folders I wanted to copy, right clicked, pressed properties, and let it scan to see how big the folders were. To my surprise, it climbed past 60GB, and came to rest at around 74GB, despite some of the bigger folders (like `Windows`) not being selected. This alone was odd, given again, it's only a 64GB drive.

My backup drive still had enough space though, so I copied it over, and I see this:

[image: (Copy dialogue saying that 160GB are being copied)]

Apparently, it's now trying to copy 160GB of data from my 64GB drive.

How is this possible? No, I don't have any external drives that are being copied as well; I selected the `Program Files`, and few folders with code related stuff, and `Users`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Comment: Read the possible duplicate for solutions to this problem.

Comment: I use space sniffer to find whats taking up space. It's still 160GB coming out of a 64GB hard drive, which your linked question doesn't appear to address.

Comment: Without knowing which files you selected exactly its going to be tough to explain this behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound Ignoring the code files which are of a negligible size, I said which files I selected. Just Program Files and Users.

Comment: Based on simple math you are only transferring 40,320MB/sec anyways so it wouldn't even be possible to transfer 160GB in only 3 hours.  I still require more information before I can explain this behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound Idk what it's talking about. The remaining space on my backup drive only lowered by 50GB, so I think windows was huffing paint thinner while I was at work.