# Missing disc space in C drive - Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

My C-drive is about `100 GB`.

I had less than `2GB` left. So i cleaned unnecessary things and could free only about `8GB`. I was wondering what would be occupying so much memory and started investigating.

Later I found, `Program Files`, `Program Files(x86)`, `Program Data`, `Python`, `Installed Drivers`, and `Users` consumes about `21 GB`

If I right click `Windows` Folder and see the properties, it shows `53GB`. But when I open the folder and if I do CTRL+A and see the properties, it shows only `31GB`. What would have happened to remaining `22GBs`?

**Edit**: All the calculations include hidden files.  I have `Show hidden files, folders and drives` option enabled

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Comment: I was going to suggest Treesize: https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/  Note, it is mentioned on the possible duplicate page!  ---  Also, I hope you have done some good defragging.  I like this one: http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/disk-defrag/

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is that some of the files are not being shown, so when you go into the folder and "select all", you are only getting properties for the visible files, not for the hidden ones.

Try going into Control Panel > Folder Options, and on the View tab, under "Hidden files and folders" select "Show hidden files, folders, and drives", and further down uncheck "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)". Then do the select-all and properties again.

On my work machine, I show 44.0 GB when all files and folders are visible, versus 29.3 GB on the default settings.

Comment: It is including Hidden folders. I have `Show hidden files, folders and drives` enabled.

Comment: Make sure to uncheck the  "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)" box. Other possible suspect that take of the free space on the drive are the pagefile C:\pagefile.sys, this is close to the size of your RAM; the hibernation file C:\hiberfil.sys - if you don't use hibernation you can disable it; System Restore points – you can delete older restore point and/or limit the space that they can take from Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

While selecting all files and showing properties, Windows skips files where your current users doesn't have **access to** (like System Restore Point data).

Run [TreesizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) **([as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token))** (this shows all folders) and look which folders "eat" most space.

[image: TreeSizeFree]