# Chrome downloads using space on C: drive, when download folder is on D:?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have Chrome installed on my C: drive, but the downloads folder for chrome is in my D: drive.

I downloaded a very big (60GB) file off of mega.co.nz using the [Chrome Mega extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mega/bigefpfhnfcobdlfbedofhhaibnlghod?hl=en).

Once it finished the file showed up in my D: drive just fine but my C: drive's used space seemed to have grown by around 60GB also.

I tried clearing the cache but that didn't work.

I was wondering why this was happening and how I could fix it?

Comment: Do you _really_ mean that the drive shrunk, or do you actually mean that an additional (and to you, unexpected) 60 GB of space was used?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant I wasn't sure how to word it

Comment: It's probably the "Mega" extension that's doing it, but that's just a guess since I'm not familiar with it, and you haven't provided a link to the specific extension in question.   What's your main goal here, to find the culprit and reason, or to find the used HDD space (to potentially free it up)?

Comment: this is the extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mega/bigefpfhnfcobdlfbedofhhaibnlghod?hl=en

Comment: And my goal is to find what is causing it and free up the space again

Comment: @user5200287 User tools like [Space Sniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/) to have a better look at your disk usage.... or tools recommended at [this](http://superuser.com/a/407971/270195)

Comment: Based on your Mega extension I would guess that the extension has it saved on the `C:` drive somewhere since Chrome is installed on `C:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It downloads to "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\File System".