# Why is the total file and folder sizes in drive C: different from the folder size in Properties?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, storage, storage-spaces

I have two different reports on the size of `C:` on Windows Server 2008 R2, by clicking the properties of `C:`, it shows 86.0 GB for "used space"; by selecting all contents (I have setup to view all hidden files and directories) under `C:\` and viewing their properties, it shows 42.0 GB for "size".

Here we see the difference almost 44 GB while total storage is 100 GB, and we need more free space. My question is this: Where does the difference come from? and what is the solution?

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like: You know that you can edit the linkage of an image without downloading it and re-uploading it, don't you?

Comment: I recently realized i could do that but you call it muscle memory or a bad habit, i can try to improve (̿▀̿ ̿Ĺ̯̿̿▀̿ ̿)̄

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

A percentage of your disk space is reserved for **System Protection** (System Restore Point) aka **Volume Shadow Copy** which can be account for the difference you are observing.

To find out space used and allocated for that you can run the following command

1. Open Command Prompt as an Administrator
2. Run `vssadmin list shadowstorage`

Also, File Allocation Table(**FAT**) or Master File Table(**MFT**) and Directories also take space in the computer.

Comment: Tools like WinDirStat or TreeSize can also be helpful for finding hidden files.

Comment: i run this command but the shadow storage does not exist

Comment: You can simply go to System Properties > Advanced > System Protection and check if it is turned ON and how much space is reserved

Comment: system protection in this server is disable,and therefore no space is reserved.

Comment: system protection in this server is disable , therefore no space is reserved.

Comment: @masoud your best bet in that case is to run one of the tools mentioned [here](http://superuser.com/a/407971/270195). I like **Space sniffer**