# 100 gigs of hard drive space not accounted for

Tags: windows

I am trying to clear out some space on my hard drive. I found that my profile folder in user is holding 115GB of data.

[image]

However when I enter this folder, select all and check... its only 18.6 GB.

How do I find this close to unanswered 100 gigs so I can delete it and free up HD space?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/8248)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when hidden files and folders are not showing.
Try enabling Tools-->Folder Options-->View-->Show hidden files, folders & drives.

b.t.w - There is a very handy tool called [SpaceSniffer](http://filehippo.com/download_spacesniffer/) which maps your entire drive and display the storage allocation with simple but powerfull GUI.

Comment: Don't forget to also disable Tools > Folder Options > View > Hide protected operating system files

Answer (score 1):

Potential reason (if it's not the 'hidden' files/folders explanation):
Windows puts links in your user's profile directory, so you are basically including other parts of the hard disk in the count, as well as double or triple count areas that are linked twice (or more). That would mean that there are not really 100 GB more in there, it just seems so.
If you use the 'select all/properties', the code is a bit more clever, and discards double counting.