# What was the last thing to consume space?

Tags: windows-7, file-search, disk-cleanup

I did a **disk cleanup** to free about 1GB of space, to realize moments after it was consumed by something once again.
How can I find out what took that space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Check your Windows directory for a directory named $WINDOWS.~BT.

This folder is hidden by default. To this folder Windows 7 downloading Windows 10 update in background.

To prevent this you have to remove a specific Windows Update: KB3035583.

Comment: Such directory doesn't exits, plus, updates are disabled on this machine.