# SSD drive filled up in drive D - mysterious file usage

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

This is from my thinkpad t450s which has a **Samsung 240GB SSD**. It has been running fine (and still is). But I suddenly noticed one morning that my D: drive had filled up overnight. This is a surprise because I hardly do anything to occupy disk space other than browsing the web, and reading pdfs.

D: drive is **110 GB** in size and in **MyComputer** it shows that **87.9 GBs** of it has been used. But when I go into the drive in windows explorer, select all files and folders and then do a file size query it shows that the **total size occupied by files and folders** is **24.2 GB** (there's no change of this even if I select hidden folders, system folders etc). Page file is disabled on the D: drive and the only one on C: drive is system managed. I have also disabled system restore on all partitions.

Surprisingly the disk usage is only abnormal as such in D: drive only. I have checked with WinDirStat, it shows up usage as **24.2 GB**. But when run with CCleaner it shows file usage of **87.9 GB** and describes the **~60 GB** of unexplained usage as **"other files"**.

**My question is** how can I find this mysterious disk usage/bloat that Windows Explorer cant see and only CCleaner classifies as 'other files' ? Is this a sign of disk wear with some random corrupted bit sectors ? I have checked SSD health and SMART data with software and almost all of them showed no signs of errors or warnings.

Comment: Did you run  WinDirStat as administrator, so it can check everywhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Comment: This difference is explained by running one application as an Administrator and the other as the User.  CCLeaner is reporting the correct actual usage

Comment: No this aint a duplicate of the question pointed above. What that asks is how to figure out which folders are taking up space. What Im trying to figure out is where can that file be that is taking up ~60 GB of space ? Cos it doesnt show up on Windows explorer. I ran WinDirStat as Admin (right click 'run as admin') yet no change in results. Even got a 'du' output using SysinternalsSuite which confirms WinDirStat - cant find the ~60GB usage. So far only CCleaner sees this. So what is this 60 GB usage ?

Comment: run TreeSizeFree as admin: http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/?language=EN

Comment: oh lovely  magicandre1981, it just showed the culprit. There's a folder called 'RRbackup' taking 63 GBs on D: drive and that only shows on TreeSizeFree (I wonder why it dint show on WinDirStat even with admin priv). This RRBackup is a lenovo thing. Ill get it sorted on how to remove this from here on. Thing is even if I select RRbackup folder from windows explorer (after enabling to show system folders) it only shows a file size of 0 for that folder and wont let me inspect contents. So I guess this must be protected by some software. Ill get it resolved from here. Thanks for help. Solved.

Comment: I've poste it as answer. Also try to delete the folder from inside TreeSizeFree when it runs as admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinDirStat is confusing and you should avoid it. Run [TreeSizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/?language=EN) [as admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token) it shows the usage in depth and cleaner way compared to WinStatDir.

[image]

With this sorted TreeView you can detect the causing folder easily.

Comment: Yes thanks for the suggestion. This is what helped me find the culprit. It was a folder created by a backup program that had different admin privilleges and therefore I was kept from looking into the contents. I think this was the reason WinDirStat failed to find the correct folder size yet TreeSizeFree was able to work on it.