# How to tell what last had access to and wrote to hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, ssd, defragment, disk-cleanup

I've recently been losing hard drive space. I've been doing all I can to get rid of temporary files and whatnot, but I feel like it'd be more time-efficient if there was a way to pinpoint what program or service last wrote to the hard drive.

In hopes of understanding where all this storage space is going, I was wondering if there was a program or specific view/command that detailed this for me.

Any tips?

Aside from disc cleanup, of course. I've been running that daily now but to no avail.

EDIT: My question asks what program is available to trace unique services or applications that write to my hard drive. IT has nothing to do with the file system or individual folder size. The linking question isn't so closely related as one might think.

-- T.R.G.

Comment: Its a tool called WinDirStat you have to run it as Administrator

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is process monitor by microsoft.
It combines a bunch of tools.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx

There is a toolbar at the top, and you can unclick registry, network, and anything else non-disk related.

This will generate, potential, thousands of records per second.  However, it will tell you what is using your disk.  There is a filter, I suggest you use it to limit the results to writes, and not reads as the number of results will be overwhelming.  You may want to use a bunch of excludes.