# I don't know anymore other ways of "disk clean up" for my Windows 10. There's only 448 KB left

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

[image: Low Memory]

I don't have any personal files (music, videos, etc.) inside "Windows (C:)", only third-party apps that (I really need) installed (500 mb in total). And then all that's inside are the Windows UPDATES. I don't know how to get rid of these.

At this point, there's is nothing more to delete other than Windows Updates. I've already remove all my personal files, If I start removing third-party apps, In a day or two I will go back in the same situation.

I can't use the laptop anymore, it's giving some error that's for sure because of out of memory.

I can't open Chrome browser, save pictures, do my daily stuff, etc.

If I restart it, it will randomly have space available, sometimes 100 mb, sometimes 500 mb, just around that size, but eventually after about an hour it will go just 5 mb.

Done with "Windows Update Cleanup", so that option is now gone.

[image: Windows Update Cleanup]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Your C: drive is only 20GB total. That's not really an adequate size drive these days. You're not going to be able to clean up much more on it. The OS alone takes up at least 15GB. And like Berend said, what is your actual question here?

Comment: you can resize pagefile.sys and disable or shrink hiberfil.sys, but that won't help you for long with only 20GB

Comment: This is what I would have done: Empty the recycle bin to retreive 240 MB, and install some third party software, like CCleaner. Then you get a better overview of the files on your system. But as n8te stated, 20 GB is not much to play with.

Comment: Use something like [WizTree](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows/8250#8) to visualize your disk usage. Please update your question to include the relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

Your disk capacity is 20 GB. Your OS takes 18 GB of it (with drivers etc.). Cleanup is not a good fix for you. I advice, buy a new hdd with higher capacity and better performance and use your old hdd as a extra partition.

Answer (score 0):

If hibernation is enabled, turn it off from an elevated command prompt.

From an administrators command prompt type:

```
powercfg -h off
```

this should free up a gig or two instantly.

This is a temporary solution, you should upgrade the hard drive to a larger one as suggested by others.