# Why might free space on C drive shrink by ~300MB per day

Tags: windows-10

For the past several weeks I have seen my free space on C: shrink by 300 to 400 MB per day. A couple of weeks ago this had my C drive down to < 4GB, so I deleted the old version of Windows at about 35GB; resetting free space to just under 39 GB. Now free space is down to 31GB and still falling.

I have a dual drive system with my user accounts set up on D. There should be nothing on C except installed programs and system files, which I have to a large extent verified.

I have just run Disk CleanUp, and there is no significant space being taken by temporary files or other junk.

The hidden system files PageFile.sys, SwapFile.sys and HiberFil.sys are not increasing in size.

I have not been installing any new software or games over the 3 months or so of interest.

My system has currently been up for just under three days, corresponding to a drop in free space of about 1GB, and this is the top of my Task Manager details sorted by I/O Write bytes:

[image]

Any ideas on where all this space is going?

---

**Update**

In response to the comment about a possible Bitcoin Miner virus, here is a snapshot just now of system activity:

[image]

Wouldn't I expect to see significant GPU activity in that case?

Comment: Bitcoin miner virus?

Comment: @DavidPostill: How would I detect that? And I understand it would steal CPU cycles, but why space?

Comment: Find out what is using the space. [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](//superuser.com/q/8248)&lq=1

Comment: Web browser cache? Windows updates download in background?

Comment: @DavidPostill: Thank you for that link. I have run and taken a snapshot, and will repeat in a few days to track the changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. But i fixed it.
This problem usually happens for pc's component file or WinSxS file.
You can fix it by doing some steps. here

1. click on windows logo key and then search command prompt..Then run it as administrator. then type ..' dism /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup '
2. Then enter. Wait for 100%

If it doesn't work , write `sfc /scannow` in the command prompt running cmd as administrator. It will repair your corrupted files automatically.

If it doesnt work ,download malware bytes and scan your PC. I hope that these steps would fix your problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for the reminder of this old post. I have now answered with the admission that this was, in bridge terminology, an *in-hand opponent* problem caused by my campaign saves for Empire and Napoleon Total War.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing. In Bridge, a four player partnership card game which I played for many many years at a tournament level with some modest success, we have an old quip about the four major hurdles to a successful session:

The actions of, respectively:

- Left-hand opponent;
- Right-hand opponent;
- Opposite-hand opponent (ie, Partner); and
- In-hand opponent (ie, Yours Truly).

Of course the most difficult of those to master is always in-hand opponent.

So it turns out that the cause of my grief and wonderment was your truly: creating start-turn and end-turn campaign saves, for several turns a day of Napoleon Total War and Empire Total War. It never occurred to me that they would be taking up so much space.

With red-faced embarrassment I now own up. Thank you [@HYPERSONIC RAY](https://user:1854780) for drawing this old post back to my attention.