# How to see a break down of disk space usage by other users?

Tags: windows-10, disk-space

The computer I am using has 7 other user accounts besides my own user account. Now it is running out of disk space. The operation system is Windows 10. Under "settings->storage," I can see "Other people" are using 220 GB in total. I believe there is one old user account that no one currently uses but has a lot of stuff in it. I cannot remember which one it is exactly. Is there a way to see how much of this 220 GB is used by each user so I know which user account to delete? What command can achieve this?

Comment: What do you see if you click on Other people?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Comment: Unused users profiles should be deleted.  Just deleting the user does not remove the user’s profile

Comment: @ harrymc I see "manage other people" where I can delete other users. However, the usage of space by each user is not shown

Comment: @ Ramhound could you explain "Just deleting the user does not remove the user’s profile"? So if I delete another user from my own account as an administrator, does it permanently remove their stuff and free up the space on the disk?

Answer (score 0):

To get a nice graphic display of *all* disk usage, try a third-party tool such as [TreeSize Free](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/), [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/treesize/).

In particular, look in the folders `C:\Users\[user name]`. To do so, you'll need to run the application as Administrator.