# Cant find whats taking up space on my computer

Tags: windows, hard-drive

It says my c drive is almost full, but i dont know were they are located, help??

[image]

Comment: It's probably your hibernation or page file, disable hibernation and see if it frees up the space.

Comment: Try to run that app as Administrator/use [TreeSize](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free) also as Administrator. It could be a system reserved file like a page file that's not showing on your screenshot.

Comment: There's 130GB in *Program Files (x86)* alone - maybe expand that? (Also, scroll down or expand the window so you can see the other folders at the bottom. Sort by GB usage if possible). I use TreeSize Free these days as you get a visual map as well as the folder listing.

Comment: Also try Tree Size (they have a trial version) as this is an excellent tool to analyze disk usage

Comment: @Smock WizTree is as good as TreeSize Free or WinDirStat. In this case, it won't help changing tools. If you don't know how to read it, it will be really hard to use.

Comment: @john WizTree is as good as TreeSize Free or WinDirStat. In this case, it won't help changing tools. If you don't know how to read it, it will be really hard to use.

Comment: hibernation and page file is only 20 gb combined, and there is no big files when i scroll down. The program files takes up about 60%. I guess i need to buy more disk space, i do find it a bit odd because all the stuff i have on my computer is gta 5 and sims 4 (130gb)

Comment: @LPChip that is a fair comment - they're all pretty much the same thing. I wasn't particularly advocating using another tool than the one in the OP though really, it was more of an aside. It would be useful **sorting by space usage** though (highest at the top) which was more the point I was making.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

You are using WizTree, which is helpful in this case. Go to the 2nd tab to see largest sizes for files and folders. At the top, there is a dropdown menu to limit the amount of results to 100.000, 10.000, 1.000, 100 or all. Set this to 100 and read through the list to see what is taking up.

According to your hard-to-read screenshot, your program files (x86) folder is stuffed with programs that are taking up space.

Comment: Yeah iknow my program files (x86) containes alot of files but i have only downloaded two games, so i guess im just surprised of how big they were. I probably need to buy more disk space

Answer (score 0):

It's strange how it doesn't look much on the usage bar, but it all adds up.

> Program Files (x86) : 130 GB
>   Windows : 23 GB
>   Users : 15.5 GB
>   ProgramFiles : 11 GB
>   SysVol : 8 GB
>   Games : 7 GB
>   Recovery : 4 GB
>   ProgramData : 4 GB

Believe it or not, that's already 202.5 GB and we've not counted everything

None of it is particularly notable except the 130GB in Program files (x86). It's definitely worth expanding that part of the tree to see the subfolders within that are taking up space

Comment: Thanks, i was surprised myself, i have two games that takes up most of the space in the folder. Guess i have to buy more disk space then

Answer (score -1):

You can try to press Win + R and type "cleanmgr". That will clean up all Windows Update Temp files etc.

Comment: Check the "clean up system files" option in there, that'll let you clean out windows update files and old restore points.

Comment: @Mokubai - Based on the author's screenshots, Windows already automatically has performed that cleanup, 68.4% of their disk is used by files in Program Files and Windows, another 9% is system files that will be there regardless.  The author simply has ran out of room.