# Why my C hard drive still full?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8

My C hard drive is full and i don't know the reason why . I've moved all important files such as download folder and document folder to another hard drive (in my case , i moved it to D: drive) . I've also uninstalled apps and reinstalled them at another hard drive . My program files + program files (x86) is less than 10 gb and my C drive max capacity is 95 GB .

I need to clean my C: drive but i don't know what to delete anymore , can someone give me clue what causes the hard drive to become full and what should i clean ?

For my case , my OS is windows 8 . Just saying in case that OS has something to do with the hard drive being full.

Comment: try wiztree to see what's taking up the space. [Cant find whats taking up space on my computer](https://superuser.com/q/1522694/241386)

Comment: Please edit your question with enough information to diagnose your problem

Comment: Only you can determine what is using space on your drive. Going forward, 100GB is really small for a primary drive for a Windows system. Without exceptional effort you will continue to come up against the space limits on your drive.

Answer (score 0):

Hi， please press Win + R and type "cleanmgr", check every option and tick what you want to delete. If you have update system, go to C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download and delete the download folder. By the way, if you think C drive is not big to use, we could extend it if unallocated space next to the C system volume. For details, we could check https://www.diskgenius.com/how-to/how-to-extend-c-drive.php