# Drive E on Windows 10 home edition is filled but the total folder properties shows a much lower space consumption

Tags: windows-10, disk-space

One SSD - 128 GB - Drive C
One HDD - 1TB - Drive D, E, F

The storage size of my Drive E is 310 GB. Windows is installed on Drive C. Some of the programs are installed on Drive E. I have noticed that the Drive E is totally filled 310 GB. But I only have program data of around 31 GB on the Drive E.

Following is an image of the folder properties of Drive E:

[image]

I do not see any hidden or system folder taking up space on that drive.

Tried with disk cleanup and disabling system restore on all drives. Nothing shows what is consuming that 280 GB of space.

[image]

Comment: Please provide the relevant information from [WizTree](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows/8250#8250) and provide a screenshot by editing your question

Comment: It worked. WizTree showed where the space was consumed. Surprisingly the Windows folder property ignored all those files and space! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the suggestion from Ramhound I checked the drive with WizTree and found that the SQL server was creating the dump files and it was occupying the space. For some reason windows's folder property was not calculating the actual size of the folder.

[image]

I have deleted those unwanted files and now the space is free.