# C drive getting full in windows 10 for no reason

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, disk-space, sql-server

I had 37 GB free on my main OS drive (C:) in my 512 GB SSD hard-drive. I installed a 2nd 1 TB drive anticipating needing more disk space soon. Just in few days c:\ drive got full for no apparent reason. Only thing I did was updated visual studio (which I do regularly so shouldn't be that big).

I moved stuff from c:\ to the new d:\drive and uninstalled some unused apps too to free 30+ GB disk space.

Now my c:\ drive is again full with no updates that I have performed and no new software installed. I have hardly even used the PC during this time but my PC is always on.

So why is my disk getting full? How do I know what's happening?

**Update**

I installed/ran WinDirStat as suggested in comments here is the top folder sizes.

[image]

My `Program Files` folder is too big!

Further opening the Program files, MS SQL Server is literally taking all of the space! And digging further, its the log files it creates!

[image]

I don't even use SQL Server, I only installed it with Visual Studio and plan on learning but nothing yet.

So given that, do I need reconfigure SQL Server or uninstall it? The log files are crazy.

Comment: Not to be alarmist, but you may want to check the integrity of your files. I had an experience recently (within the last 2 years) where encryption malware (ransomware) was filling up my hard drive, apparently from bulk encrypting my personal files.

Comment: You will have to provide us enough information to diagnose your problem.  I would download [WizTree](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows) and provide a screenshot.  Be sure to run the program as an Administrator otherwise you won't get accurate results.

Comment: @FormerlyPimpJuiceIT I did cmd steps (not sure about pwershell to autoclean up) and I did get back 7 GB back but still a lot more there. I don't have music or videos on my 512 GB C:\ drive and its still full with just applications, seems like something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

So my problem was SQL Server whose log folders was taking up all the space and inside that it was the actually the `dump` folder which was 348 GB large so not exactly the log files. It has growing number .dmp files.

I had installed it (actually couple of times because first it failed) but never really used and don't have any critical data. There are signs the installation is wrong as I have two similar looking folders. Cleaning up and installing correctly should fix it.

[image]

Comment: Good catch! Glad Ramhound gave you the suggestion to help you find the specific problem. Read over https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/11/08/sql-server-many-sqldump-files-consuming-lot-disk-space/ and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87112/the-sql-server-log-folder-is-expanding-because-of-the-sql-dump-files-what-to-do too. If they keeop coming back, you might still have some work though.