# Windows 10 - C drive full but no files

Tags: windows-10, ssd, disk-space

Last week I've noticed that my C drive was out of disk space. So for the past few days I've been looking into what folders occupy my disk space, and started cleaning up a bit. I've ended up freeing 75 GB.

Ever since, I've seen that my efforts to free up disk space were useless. Today already, I'm right back at only 12 GB free disk space again. Once again I've started looking into what folders are taking up space.

[image: Disk usage]

Read this picture as follows:

- Invisible files/folders are shown in Windows Explorer
- My SSD has a capacity of 475 GB
- All files/folders on my disk are taking 166 GB (only 1/3 of my capacity)
- My disk is full

Why does this keep happening? Where do these **309 Gigabytes** go to?

I'm a .NET developer, so I [do have SQL-server installed](https://superuser.com/a/1606258/1225721), but even so, the file size of the SQL-server cache folders should show up in the measurements.

[image: diskmgmt]

### EDIT

I did a scan using the tool that @Señor CMasMas suggested (run as administrator)

[image: MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER/SMSSQL/Log/Polybase/dump taking up all disk space]

And it's indeed the folder **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\Polybase\dump** that's taking up all disk space (literally 256 GB), even though you can't see it under the **Program Files** folder size.

### EDIT 14/06/2021

I had installed the latest version of SQL Server. Now we're 3 weeks in, and once again my C drive is getting seeded with the same file:

[image: Microsoft SQL Server folder 107 GB in size]

Comment: [This free program](http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/) called simply "disk scanner" is the best tool I have ever seen for visualizing where your space went.  It is not smart enough to ignore hard links or junctions.  I find that programs like the one mentioned or WinDirStat don't make it easy to see legit vs non-legit BIG STUFF.

Comment: One place that I've found my disk space to have been chewed up on some computers is C:\WINDOWS\LOGS\CBS; for some reason, the massive space consumption there didn't get reflected in the normal windows disk space summaries. Having lots of large CBS logs, however, indicates that there are other problems with your system.

Comment: If you run Explorer as administrator it would also show you the size, it cannot calculate it if it has no permissions to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of tools available to help diagnose lost disk space.

One such tool which I've used for many years (more than I care to mention) is TreeSize. They have a free version, which you can download from [here](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free).

Scan your `C:\` drive, and order the results in descending order by size. If `pagefile.sys` or `hiberfil.sys` turn out to be the offending items, look at moving your pagefile off your SSD, or capping its size, and/or disable hibernation.

[image]

Alternative tools include but aren't limited to [SpaceSniffer](http://www.uderzo.it/main_products/space_sniffer/download.html), [windirstat](https://windirstat.net/), ...

Comment: I did just turn off my pagefile, but it was only 12 GB so that wouldn't be the main issue...