# How to check which folder is increasing size recently?

Tags: windows, file-management, windows-server-2008-r2

One of my servers got virus and it usually get full storage.

How could I check which folder is increasing size recently or which files added recently so that I could delete files for more space?

I had freed up all available space (known not-used-folders, disk cleanup)

I already installed antivirus (malwarebytes, KAV) and scanned virus but no help. Could not reinstall windows for now so must use some temporary methods to keep this server alive.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Comment: There are several questions on SuperUser about finding out what is filling your disk space up. What research have you done? Also, while you think you have a virus, you've checked multiple ways and haven't found any indication, so what makes you think you have a virus still?

Comment: @music2myear Thank you for that link. Sorry I didn't mention it clearly that I had installed antivirus and scanned, quarantined/deleted many virus, but no help. And I have searched but don't know good keywords: https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enVN887VN887&sxsrf=ALeKk01Q81azXHuFsMJsduUzIwcFKiUz8Q%3A1610503579799&ei=m1X-X_udMNCo-Qa7i5-4BA&q=windows+manage+storage+spaces&oq=windows+manage+storage+s https://www.google.com/search?q=which+folder+increase+size+recently&rlz=1C1CHBF_enVN887VN887&oq=which+folder+increase+size+recently

Comment: Some third party tool may help you, kindly check if methods mentioned in the following thread can help you: [Best method to track folder size growth over time?](https://serverfault.com/questions/105448/best-method-to-track-folder-size-growth-over-time)

Comment: Oh, if you found many viruses, you need to reimage the computer. Especially if it is a server you must not trust it for any purpose. It's also clear you're running an old version of server and connecting it to the internet. This is very, very bad for many reasons, including the one you've discovered. Also, the linked question is still the answer to what you've asked, and there's also questions about virus clean up.