# System drive fills up for no reason

Tags: windows-10, disk-space, dell-inspiron

have 128 gb of ssd, and my system drive is located there. Every time I reinstall windows I get 60 gb of free space. After a month or so it becomes 0 very quickly even though I don't install anything on my c drive. And it's not temp files because even after I delete them, it clears only 4gb of space. My dell C:/ProgramData/dell now makes up a total of 400mb, before i reinstalled windows it made up 18gb, and I couldn't delete it even after changing permissions. Would be nice to know how to uninstall it, as I am aware of how to install all the drivers manually. Also yesterday as soon as I reinstalled I had 60 gb of free space as of today I already have only 51 gb of free space.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows

Comment: You can safely delete any Dell software installed on your system.  It's not necessary for your system to function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Comment: 128 GB is a bit small for Windows 10 system drive. Other OS, such as Linux, can comfortably run in 20 GB or less, and handle updates, but Windows essentially duplicates  the system folders, to allow reversion, after major updates, until the duplicates are cleaned up.

Comment: I ran I to this problem years ago. The issue was old update files. I'm think that running Disk Cleanup allowed me to remove the old crud freeing many gigs of space

Comment: I don't know about YOUR Dell.. but mine came with 128GB SSD primary drive and 1TB HDD secondary drive.  For months, I moved huge stuff to the the 1TB secondary and used NTFS junctions to link back to the primary drive.  This worked but what a PITA!!  I eventually gave up and replaced the 128GB SSD with a 512GB SSD.  Life has been good ever since.