# Deleting Windows.old in Windows10 by way of the System Cleanup, less than half of the space expected to be released was

Tags: windows-10, upgrade, disk-space, windows-10-upgrade, disk-cleanup

My Windows.old folder was ~26GB. Rather than directly deleting it, I used Windows disk cleanup (CleanMgr.exe) to Cleanup past Windows installations - also showing that it would free 26GB. After doing this however, it free up approx. 12.7GB rather than 26. What happend to the other 13.3GB it was supposed to have released?

The current OS is Windows 10 20H2 (upgraded from 1909)

Comment: Run [WizTree](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows) as an Administrator and provide the screenshot necessary to diagnose your issue

Comment: Restart the PC some cleanup may be done during reboot.

Comment: Thank you guys. These are helpful advices.