# The Harddisk size on treesize is smaller than actual space on my C drive

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, disk-space

[The link for the image shows the actual harddisk space vs the harddisk space in Treesize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6zOh.png)It all happened after I deleted a virtual machine from virtualbox, and noticed the space on my hard disk didn't free up. I checked the directory where the virtual machine image is stored, that was empty too. I have tried restarting the system, system restore, dskmgmt.msc, etc. But haven't been able to get back those 4Gbs I am missing in Treesize. Any suggestions?

Edit: I found the reason, Treesize is not showing the actual overall size of the drive but the size of files I have in those drives.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure what else to write. Is it possible for you to help me understand what else I need to mention? It is my first time ever doing this thing.

Comment: Screenshots that indicate what is using your missing 4 GB of space would be helpful.  [WizTree](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows) provides a better overview of your disk usage.  Be sure to run it as an Administrator otherwise it won't report the proper disk usage.  That advice also applies to Treesize by the way

Comment: First of all, thank you so much! I realized it is not the allocated space that is bugging me but the size of the disk, so sorry for that mistake, I will correct it right now. I have added an image that shows the difference between the Harddisk size that the PC shows vs what Treesize shows, also, Treesize is running in Admin mode. I am unable to understand why the size is lesser than the space properties show.

Comment: OMG @Ramhound .. that page you referenced has every awesome tool there is!! :)  I use all of them (depending on need)..

Comment: Also @AbhishekOberoi .. be aware that sometimes disk tools are not smart and reference files that are hard linked more than once.  I doubt the windows view you provide has this problem but it is possible.  An example is that there are virtually no Microsoft files in the system32 directory.  These are all hard links to versions in the %windir%\WinSxS folder.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Thanks to you too!

Comment: TreeSize always shows ~4-6 GB higher data usage than exists on a Windows system drive. I assume that is because it doesn't calculate NTFS reparse points, soft- and hardlinks not correctly.