# Multiple hard drive partitions

Tags: partitioning

I just installed a 1tb hd on my laptop as I was running low on memory, after cleaning up images/music/movies I was still low so I bought a secondary hd...current one was 256 gig, new on is 1tb.  While setting it up in disk manager I noticed I have several partitions on the old drive, 4 are labeled as recovery and one is 13gigs and another is 1gig, all say "100% free"

I've uploaded an image of my disk manager screen, too few posts for it to automatically show

I've seen some folks say when deleting these it can cause windows to not update properly, is this true?  And do I need all these partitions?  And how can I free up the unused memory they are taking up if not needed?

[image: disk manager screen]

Comment: Don't confuse **memory** which is the computer's RAM, with **storage**, which is the amount of hard drive space you have.

Comment: Before screwing with the system partitions, move your pagefile, temp, and internet cache to the new drive.  If you have some huge games installed, uninstall them and reinstall them to the new drive.  Then use the tools provided on [THIS PAGE](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows) to clean up whatever bloat is left.  BTW.. I learned about that page from @Ramhound .  I can tell by the nature of the question that if you screw with your partitions, you will probably regret it.

Comment: tetsujin-it should be obvious I was not. Thanks for nitpicking grammar instead of paying attention or helping...*slowclap you must feel proud

senior masmas-While appreciate the advice I do not the condescending tone.  I clearly stated I wasn't going to do ANYTHING because obviously I don't know what I'm doing...which is why I was asking in the first place-you didn't answer my question at all so curb the 'tud

Answer (score 1):

A bit of googling already gave me an answer:

The partition labelled "EFI system partition" holds data Windows and your computer need to boot. [<sup>[1]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition)

The three other partitions are clearly labelled as well. They're recovery partitions, they're used to revert windows to its original state.[<sup>[2]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recovery_disc#Recovery_partitions) Why there are multiple of them is explained [here](https://win10.guru/why-do-i-have-multiple-recovery-partitions-the-explanation/).

Also, keep in mind what *[Tetsujin](https://superuser.com/questions/1663021/multiple-hard-drive-partitions#comment2548649_1663021)* mentioned when talking about computers. Memory usually means RAM.

Comment: computer folks love to nitpick grammar to feel superior-it was obvious I knew the difference-you clearly realized that too yet still needed an ego boost. you folks point out how easily you googled it, same reason. I came hand out and didn't pretend to be knowledgeable, thanks, I already felt stupid*slow clap. hope you went "showed him" what a great person you two are. when I answer nooby tech questions I don't give them a hard time if approached with humility,I'm not an ahole,it was hard enough for them to ask me in the first place. I did google this first but you KNOW what to google, I don't