# How can I increase my shrink volume on C drive?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, windows-11, disk-space

My C drive has 37.7 GB free and I wanted to unallocate 30 GB to house my Linux root. But on disk manager, I couldn't seem to shrink beyond 304 MB. So I followed the Solution 1 in [this link](https://www.diskpart.com/disk-management/unable-to-shrink-c-drive-0310.amp.html) to deal with the unmoveable files. Unfortunately, it only increased the available shrink volume t0 14.3 GB. What do I do now?

My C drive is the only drive on SSD disk.

Comment: "What do I do now?" - Disable the hibernation and page file

Comment: Use a linux live USB

Comment: @Ramhound I did that. Read the description.

Comment: @GrGr11 - After you disabled the hibernation and page files you rebooted your system?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes. After the reboot the shrink volume became from 403 MB to 14.3 GB but I need more since 37.5 GB is free

Comment: A screenshot from [WizTree](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows) would be helpful.