# C drive losing space overnight windows 10

Tags: windows, hard-drive

My c drive is continually losing space. Once, it was 36 mB, then 5 mins later, when I came back from doing something, which implies it was idle the whole time, it was 24 mb. 300 mb last night, and now?

[image]

0B.

I am going to add more space to c drive, but if it keeps decreasing space like this, it's going to be useless. The storage settings shows this:

[image]

Then this:

[image]

If there is 6.07 BG of temporary storage, why can I clear only 11 Mb?
Disk cleanup is even worse. Only 1 mb of temp files left to clear, and 13 Mb of system files. Bitdefender antivirus found nothing in a full system scan. Looks to me any space I have will be rendered obsolete by this gigantic anonymous space eater. Why is this happening? What is causing this? Here is a list of all my installed apps( all in D drive ):

[image]

And here's c drive(windows apps):

[image]

And program files 86( c drive ):

[image]

Here is a screenshot of windirstat:
[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Update: I ran easeUs clean genius, and it's truly a genius. It cleared 10 Gb of data that the windows in built apps weren't able to. But my problem is still valid.

Comment: What version of Windows? I suspect I know what’s going on.

Comment: It's written on the title. Windows 10

Comment: Yes; But what version of Windows 10 and is the system compatible with Windows 11?

Comment: Version 10.0.19043 Build 19043
Yes, it's compatible

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of Windows Update?  Here is what I suspect, your system being compatible without any compatibility blockers, is attempting to download Windows 11. Given you have an extremely small system drive, this of course is filling up the drive, with the update. Normally I would expect this to be from a Windows 10 feature update (22H2) but that can be installed through a enablement package. Running the Cleanup Tool as an Administrator would be provider insight then the screenshots you have already provided.

Comment: I would use [WizTree](https://superuser.com/questions/8248) and update your question to provide additional information about your disk.

Comment: @Ramhound I have added information about the disk using WinDirStat

Answer (score -1):

You can use [TreeSize Free](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free)* to detect the largest files on your computer (set the scan option to your entire C: drive and filter by size, ascending). But, **don't just delete the biggest files immediately!** They could be important. Update your question with your findings.

*TreeSize **Free** is actually freeware and will not "expire". The relatively moderate feature set of the freeware version will do for this case. *(Disclaimer: I do not work for JAM Software and do not mean to advertise.)*